# Bacula web: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

Tags: 16.04, apache2, backup

I tried testing bacula-web on 16.04 but failed test with error as title "SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file"

What permission should I use?

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/bacula/
total 68
-rw-r----- 1 www-data bacula 63488 May 11 13:25 bacula.db
-rw------- 1 bacula   bacula     0 May 11 13:25 ubuntu-dir.conmsg
```

config.php used

```
// SQLite bacula catalog
 $config[0]['label'] = 'Dev backup server';
 $config[0]['db_type'] = 'sqlite';
 $config[0]['db_name'] = '/var/lib/bacula/bacula.db';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the Bacula-Web current maintener.

IMHO, maybe this solution will fix Bacula-Web problem but at the same time, if you run bacula-dir as a non-root user, this will avoid write permissions on the SQLite database file.

What would be better is (if bacula run with user bacula)
$ sudo chown bacula:www-data /var/lib/bacula
Please tell me if this works too (Bacula and Bacula-Web)

I would be happy to update Bacula-Web documentation if needed.

P.S: feel free to open a bug report or feature request in Bacula-Web bug tracker -> http://bugs.bacula-web.org

Best regards

Comment: yes, that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Folder sqlite3 database resides also need to have write permission for web user. So to solve this, what I did was:

```
sudo chown www-data /var/lib/bacula
```